# How to get monitor resolution independent of scaling?

Tags: screen-resolution

I need to obtain the horizontal and vertical monitor resolution, independent of the display scaling in use by Windows. At scaling of 100%, there is no problem; GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) returns the actual horizontal resolution of the monitor in pixels. On a 1920 x 1080 monitor, that function returns 1920. However, if the scaling is set to 125% on the same computer, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) returns 1536. The problem with that is, if I use that number in a call to BitBlt() to copy the screen, it copies only a partial screen, the left three quarters or so. My program does not know that it has to use 1920 to capture the entire screen, because Windows is telling it the horizontal monitor resolution is 1536. I tried using GetDeviceCaps() and using GetMonitorInfo() to get the monitor resolution, but they return the same values as GetSystemMetrics(). Windows is reporting a monitor resolution it is not actually using for BitBlt() and also for SetPixel(). The latter function draws to a location as though the screen resolution were 1920. For example, at scaling of 125%, SetPixel() draws a pixel at the x coordinate of 1500 not near the right edge of the screen, but at about three quarters from the left. SetPixel() will draw near the right edge of the screen if I tell it to draw at the x coordinate 1900, so evidently it is not interpreting screen coordinates as reported by GetSystemMetrics().

How can I get the actual monitor resolution in pixels, regardless of the scaling?

Comment: There is [`GetScaleFactorForDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorfordevice), which should give you enough information to get the correct values. Beware that if there is more than 1 screen/monitor, the function requires a parameter defining from which screen you're trying to get info (it's zero indexed, btw)

Comment: I am calling GetScaleFactorForMonitor() in my program, and that gives the scaling percentage in use. That function supersedes GetScaleFactorForDevice(). I deduce you are saying my program can calculate the actual monitor resolution from the scaling percentage and the resolution reported by GetSystemMetrics(). In this case, 1.25 x 1536 = 1920, so that appears to be a solution to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I set scaling in Display Settings to 150%, GetScaleFactorForMonito() returns a value of 140%, while GetSystemMetrics() returns 1280 for horizontal resolution. While 1.5 x 1280 gives a correct result 1920, 1.4 x 1280 gives the incorrect result 1792.

Comment: Worse, if scaling in Display Settings is set to 125%. GetScaleFactprForMonitor() returns 100%, leaving no way to calculate the actual monitor resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
RECT rBox;
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
GetClipBox(hdcScreen, &rBox);
```

When GetClipBox() returns, rBox contains dimensions in pixels of the entire screen, regardless of scaling factor. They are the same dimensions for all scaling factors. With screen resolution set to 1920 x 1080, the function sets rBox.left to 0 and rBox.right to 1920.

Comment: It works well for me on Windows 10, but on Windows Server 2008, GetClipBox returns NULLREGION